# Why does date::floor calculate a date 2 days back when derived from time_t

Tags: c++, date

I have a [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) program with a wxDatePickerCtrl and I am using [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to work with dates in C++17.

When a date gets changed, I want to get a string representation of the current selected date (by using `date::format()`).

I do that as the following:

- Get the date from the [wxDateEvent](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_date_event.html)
- Call the [GetTicks](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_date_time.html#a99263946a9a2ece83421411081c02378) method which returns a `time_t`
- Convert to `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` using `from_time_t()`
- Finally convert to `date::days`

On initialization, the dates are fine. But when I go *back* one day, `date::floor` calculates the date *two* days back. However, `date::ceil` calculates the date correctly.

Please see attached screenshot:

[image: On startup and going 1 day back]

MRE:

```cpp
#include <date/date.h>

#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
#include <wx/datectrl.h>
#include <wx/dateevt.h>

class MainFrame final : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame()
        : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "wxDatesAndDateDotH")
        , pDateCtrl(nullptr)
        , pDateLabel(nullptr)
        , pDateDotHFloorLabel(nullptr)
        , pDateDotHCeilLabel(nullptr) {
        CreateControls();
        FillControls();

        Bind(
            wxEVT_DATE_CHANGED,
            &MainFrame::OnDateSelection,
            this,
            wxdIDC_DATESLCTR
        );
    }

    virtual ~MainFrame() = default;

    void OnDateSelection(wxDateEvent& event) {
        pDateLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("Date Selected:    %s", event.GetDate().FormatISODate()));

        auto& eventDate = event.GetDate();
        auto dateTicks = eventDate.GetTicks();

        auto dateFloor = date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateTicks));
        auto dateCeil = date::ceil<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateTicks));

        pDateDotHFloorLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::floor =       %s", date::format("%F", dateFloor)));
        pDateDotHCeilLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::ceil =         %s", date::format("%F", dateCeil)));
    }

private:
    void CreateControls() {
        auto mainPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

        auto mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        mainPanel->SetSizer(mainSizer);

        auto starterLabel = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "wxDates");
        mainSizer->Add(starterLabel, wxSizerFlags().Center());

        auto dateSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        mainSizer->Add(dateSizer);

        auto dateLabel = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Date: ");
        dateSizer->Add(dateLabel, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL, 5).CenterVertical());

        pDateCtrl = new wxDatePickerCtrl(mainPanel, wxdIDC_DATESLCTR, wxDateTime::Now());
        dateSizer->Add(pDateCtrl, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL, 5));

        pDateLabel = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Date Selected: --");
        mainSizer->Add(pDateLabel, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL, 5));

        pDateDotHFloorLabel = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "date::floor = --");
        mainSizer->Add(pDateDotHFloorLabel, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL, 5));

        pDateDotHCeilLabel = new wxStaticText(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "date::ceil = --");
        mainSizer->Add(pDateDotHCeilLabel, wxSizerFlags().Border(wxALL, 5));
    }

    void FillControls() {
        auto dateTimeNow = wxDateTime::Now();
        auto dateTimeNowTicks = dateTimeNow.GetTicks();

        pDateLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("Date Selected:    %s", dateTimeNow.FormatISODate()));

        auto dateFloor = date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateTimeNowTicks));
        auto dateCeil = date::ceil<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateTimeNowTicks));

        pDateDotHFloorLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::floor =       %s", date::format("%F", dateFloor)));
        pDateDotHCeilLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::ceil =         %s", date::format("%F", dateCeil)));
    }

    wxDatePickerCtrl* pDateCtrl;
    wxStaticText* pDateLabel;
    wxStaticText* pDateDotHFloorLabel;
    wxStaticText* pDateDotHCeilLabel;

    enum {
        wxdIDC_DATESLCTR = wxID_HIGHEST + 1001
    };
};

class Application : public wxApp
{
public:
    Application() = default;
    virtual ~Application() = default;

    bool OnInit() override {
        auto frame = new MainFrame();
        frame->Show(true);
        SetTopWindow(frame);

        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(Application);
```

My question is why does `date::floor` calculate a date 2 days in the past when "initialized" from a `time_t`?

My problem is solved by using `date::ceil` at the end of the day, but I'm curious about `date::floor`.

My use case is that you cannot go into the future, only today and past dates.

Comment: `date` has different semantics than `datetime`.  The `time` part makes all the difference.

Comment: I've looked through the WxWidgets documentation and it isn't clear to me what `event.GetDate()` is returning.  I suspect it is returning your local date.  `time_t` and subsequently `dateFloor` is a UTC date.  I suspect you're looking at two different dates because of your local time zone's UTC offset.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I've done some debugging it looks like the wxWidgets date is set to my local time zone date, for example 2023-09-30T00:00:00. Thus `time_t` converts to UTC which means it goes to the previous day (i.e. 2023-09-29T22:00:00). Thank you, I need figure out to get the `wxDateTime` to be in UTC itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eljay and @Howard Hinnant mentioned in the comments, the issue was time.

wxWidgets was sending a `wxDateTime` through the event handler set to your time zone locale. i.e. the event handler would receive a date as UTC+0200 (my time zone), for example 2023-09-30T00:00:00. Thus, calling `GetTicks()` would result in `time_t` converting that time to UTC, which would result in a date time (using the previous example) as 2023-09-29T22:00:00.

Below is the changes in `OnDateSelection()`. I've highlighted the change to force the `wxDateTime` to be in UTC

```cpp
void OnDateSelection(wxDateEvent& event) {
    pDateLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("Date Selected:    %s", event.GetDate().FormatISOCombined()));

    auto eventDate = event.GetDate();
    auto dateUtc = eventDate.MakeFromTimezone(wxDateTime::UTC); // important change
    auto dateUtcTicks = dateUtc.GetTicks();

    auto dateFloor = date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateUtcTicks));
    auto dateCeil = date::ceil<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(dateUtcTicks));

    pDateDotHFloorLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::floor =       %s", date::format("%F", dateFloor)));
    pDateDotHCeilLabel->SetLabel(wxString::Format("date::ceil =         %s", date::format("%F", dateCeil)));
}
```

PS:
I've created a [github repo](https://github.com/ifexception/wxWidgetsAndDateDotH) with the MRE and latest changes